# How could I align two ggpubr histograms so they are facing each other?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to align two histograms so they face each other, like the image of this link:
[Example image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6Q4.png)

I had the two individual histograms for each group, and I tried to align them using the function align_plots from cowplot. However, I end with something like this:
![My aligned plots] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/E04UQ.png)

Here is the code I used to align them, and regarding any changes in the align and axis parameters, the image still result in something similar to the second one posted above:

```
aligned_hist <- cowplot::align_plots(Asyhist, Symhist, align = "hv", axis = "b")
align_hist <- ggdraw(aligned_hist[[1]]) + draw_plot(aligned_hist[[2]])
align_hist
```

Sorry for not posting the images directly, but I am new in stack overflow and didn't allow me to do it. Hope somebody could help me to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about ggpubr histograms, but an approach with vanilla ggplot2 would be to use `after_stat()` to change  the value depending on the group.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(100, 1), rnorm(100, 2)),
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = group)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(ifelse(group == 2, -1, 1) * count))
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>